# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2. Required by: project :

Tags: android, compiler-errors, signed-apk

I am trying to compile project on android studio, and I keep geeting this error

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2.

I just want to generate the apk, and I don't understand what cause this behavior.

Comment: Do you have the required package? If not install it through SDK Tools. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: 11.0.2 or 11.2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `SDK Manger`and download

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2
```

this will resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: this has been solved, i downloaded and updated all the google play services and repositories....thanks a million,

Comment: i am glad to help you